# How to places a timer on Splash Screen (preloader) in Javafx

Tags: javafx, timer, splash-screen

I asked the question in the title in a earlier thread I created, since the rule is one question per thread. I am re-stating the question as I answered my own question and I'm sure that others new to javafx and programming can benefit from the answer.

The problem I was having was caused do to the size of the program, I had nothing going on in the initiation phase of my program. So the Splash Screen would launch, then immediately close and launch the main scene. However, I needed the splash screen to display for a reasonable amount of time prior to launching the program. in order to display my Splash Screen I used the answer below to solve my problem.

Comment: Fabian, does the edit provide the necessary information?

Answer (score 0):

in the initiation phase of the main class add the following line to set a timer.

```
try {

        Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

note: the time measurement is in milliseconds (1000 milliseconds = 1 second)